# How to separate the operator inside the array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**I did this from the database**.

how to find the the $dependency separator after explode i want explode that array .

```
$dependency = 2/3&3/6;

$find =  explode('&',$dependency);

string(7) "2/3&3/6"
```

I am getting like,

```
sarray(2) {
  [0]=>string(3) "2/3"
  [1]=>string(3) "3/6"
}
```

But i want the result to be like this:

```
 sarray(2) {
      [0]=>array(2) {
                       [0]=>string(1) "2"
                       [1]=>string(3) "3"
       }

      [1]=>array(2) {
                       [0]=>string(1) "3"
                       [1]=>string(3) "6"
               }
}
```

please help to find the this array separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go  first explode with '&' then with '/' on each array item

```
$str = "2/3&3/6";
$arr= explode('&',$str);
foreach($arr as $val){
    $arrData[]= explode('/',$val);
}
echo "</pre>";
print_r($arrData);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need read the array using `foreach` then explode again to get the desired result.

```
$dependency = '2/3&3/6';
$find =  explode('&',$dependency);
$result = array();

foreach($find as $val){
$result = array_merge($result,explode("/",$val));//Store all the values in one array
or
$result[]=explode("/",$val); //store array as key
}
```

var_dump($result);

Comment: iam confuse who added first

Comment: both are appeared at the same time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149675/discussion-between-jeevanswamy21-and-lalithkumar).

Answer (score 2):

You have to further use `foreach` to separate string again

```
$dependency = "2/3&3/6";
$find =  explode('&',$dependency);
$new_array=array();
foreach ($find as $key => $value) {
  $new_array[]=explode('/',$value);
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
```

Comment: iam confuse who added first